# jQuery: content to show when enter key is pressed

Tags: jquery, html, enter

I am trying to display some content when a button is clicked (which it works perfectly with my code), but I would also like it to be shown when an enter key is pressed as well.

The console is running well with an error of " *getFigures could not be defined* " and no content has been shown! I have tried a lot of different methods suggested, but still with no luck... It would be wonderful if anyone could address where have I put wrong please?

Here is my code below and you may find the full code in the link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/rokvowjv/5/):

HTML:

```
    <section id="fetch">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name here" id="term" />
         <button type = "button" id="search">ENTER</button>
    </section>

    <section id="content">
        <div id = "figures">
            <script>
            </script>
        </div>

        <div id ="name">
            <div id = "nameBox">
            </div>
            <div id = "nameText">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id = "message">        
            <div id = "messageBox">
            </div>
            <div id = "greetingText">
            </div>
            <div id = "messageText">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#search').click(displayContent);     // the value of the #term is being called within the displayContent();

$('#term').keyup(function(event){
   if(event.keyCode == 13){
       displayContent();
       getFigures();
   }
});

$('#term').keypress(function(event){        // this function looks redundant...?
    if(event.which == 13){
    $('#search').click(displayContent);
        displayContent();
        getFigures();
    }
});
```

Thanks a lot :))) x

**EDIT:** The updated fiddle of what I want is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/rokvowjv/15/) for anyone's reference :))) x

Comment: where is this `getFigures()`?

Comment: The function you are saying is redundant is in fact redundant, yes. It only makes it so the `displayContent` and `getFigures` are run twice on every enter key click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getFigures` is defined in the scope of the function `displayContent` and does not exists outside this scope.
You try to call `getFigures` in `$('#term').keypress(function (event))` which is outside the `displayContent` scope and so `getFigures` does not exist.

Put `getFigures` out of the `displayContent` function and it works.

**edit:** You also need to add the `type` variable as an attribute to the `getFigures` function so you can pass it appropriately.

See my new jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rokvowjv/12/

**Note**: you delete the `#figures` div by emptying the `#content` div, I add the image in the content instead to display it, but I am not sure if that is what you want. 
You tried to add the image output to the figures div, but since you first delete the div it would not work.

Comment: Hello Bas, thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't work... There is no content being displayed although the console is printing well and accordingly... Do you have any idea why please? Cheers x

Comment: I changed my answer, you need to do a few more changes to make it work. See the jsfiddle for all the code.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is not what I want but it gives me a hindsight on how to do what I want :))) Thanks a lot and you may find my updated code here: https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/rokvowjv/15/ CHEERS:DDD x

Answer (score 2):

Please check this:

https://jsfiddle.net/rokvowjv/8/

only this much code is required to capture `enter` key and load the contents.

```
$('#term').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        displayContent();
    }
});
```

Also while testing it please put "Alexis" in text field and then press enter. If you do this then even "FIGURES PRINTED" will get printed in console.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, however no content is being displayed although the console is running every log that it supposed to be... Would you have any idea why please? Cheers x

Answer (score 1):

take `getFigures` outside of `displayContent` so that it will be available when the call is made and call `getFigures(type)` in `displayContent`.[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/suchit/fox56s93/).see the console it will show the name entered.

```
 var getFigures = function (type) {

        if (type == "mf") {

            $('#figures').prepend('<img src = "images/mf.png" height = "500px" width = "500px" />');
            console.log("mf found");

        } else if (type == "mm") {

            $('#figures').prepend('<img src = "images/mm.png" height = "500px" width = "500px" />');
            console.log("mm found");

        } else if (type == "ff") {

            $('#figures').prepend('<img src = "images/ff.png" height = "500px" width = "500px" />');
            console.log("ff found");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Suchit, thank you very much for your suggestion. I have tried it but there is still no content being shown although the console is running well and accordingly... Would you have any idea why please? Cheers x